# "One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key..."

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-mobilehub

[image]

This error occurs in AWS Mobile Hub while Testing my API that connects to DynamoDB. It says 'Questions' key is not defined but it definitely is..

Comment: I guess something somewhere is getting lost. Seems you send the item, but does your endpoint send it to dynamodb ? It seems not.

Comment: I believe so because I can do a GET request and supply a key